# If i import exit() from sys, which exit will it run?

Tags: python

In python if i import the exit module from sys will it run the normal exit() or sys.exit()

```
from sys import exit
print "Bla bla bla"
exit()
```

Comment: You'll get `sys.exit`, not `__builtins__.exit`.  Out of curiosity ... why does it matter?  `__builtints__.exit` works by the same mechanisms that `sys.exit` uses ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from a import b` assigns the variable named `b` to the imported object, so you're overshadowing the built-in `exit`.

You can also just print out a string representation of `exit` to see this. Run

```
print(exit, type(exit))
from sys import exit
print(exit, type(exit))
```

to see:

```
(Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit, <class 'site.Quitter'>)
(<built-in function exit>, <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>)
```

Of course, there is rarely a reason to overshadow a built-in. Why not

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

instead?